# Is progress to challenges counted in classic/challenge maps?

Tags: doom-2016

Is progress towards challenges or runes counted in the classic maps you can unlock? For example, earning 2500 points of armor for a rune challenge, or getting 75 Glory Kills. Is that same progress also counted inside specific rune challenges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you enter a rune challenge, all of your equipement is pre-set. As far as I saw, you may have additionnal rules like no movement allowed, no loot from ennemies.
Since you have no rune equipped in any rune challenge, there are no chance of having progress in them.

I have yet to unlock a classic map to find out if you can equip runes in them, but since these levels are pretty short, it would be better to roam the early levels of the main campaign in order to maximize your runes.